# WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedItem or SelectedValue not working

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

**Update**

After a bit of investigating.  What seems to be the issue is that the SelectedValue/SelectedItem is occurring before the Item source is finished loading.  If I sit in a break point and wait a few seconds it works as expected.  Don't know how I'm going to get around this one.

**End Update**

I have an application using in WPF using MVVM with a ComboBox.  Below is the ViewModel Example.  The issue I'm having is when we leave our page and migrate back the ComboBox is not selecting the current Value that is selected.

**View Model**

```cs
public class MyViewModel
{
     private MyObject _selectedObject;
     private Collection<Object2> _objects;
     private IModel _model;

     public MyViewModel(IModel model)
    {
         _model = model;
         _objects = _model.GetObjects();
    }

    public Collection<MyObject> Objects
    {
         get
         {
              return _objects;
         }
         private set
         {
              _objects = value;
         }
     }

     public MyObject SelectedObject
     {
          get
          {
              return _selectedObject;
          }
          set
          {
               _selectedObject = value;
          }
      }
 }
```

For the sake of this example lets say MyObject has two properties (Text and Id).  My XAML for the ComboBox looks like this.

XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" Height="23"  Width="auto" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedObject,Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Text"
    SelectedValuePath="Id">
```

No matter which way I configure this when I come back to the page and the object is reassembled the ComboBox will not select the value.  The object is returning the correct object via the get in the property though.

I'm not sure if this is just an issue with the way the ComboBox and MVVM pattern works.  The text box binding we are doing works correctly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your viewmodel, and then raise the `PropertyChanged` event when the `SelectedItem` gets set?

If this in itself doesn't fix it, then you will be able to manually raise the `PropertyChanged` event yourself when navigating back to the page, and that should be enough to get WPF to redraw itself and show the correct selected item.

Comment: Our actual implementation Inherits from a ViewBase class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.  I am raising the PropertyChange but the combo box remains blank.

Comment: Even better if I put break points in and wait a bit it works.  Me thinks my selecteditem is getting set before the binding of the combobox is done.  Urgh.

Comment: I forgot to raise the PorpertyChanged event on navigation back to the page.

Answer (score 47):

Setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` worked for me!

Comment: Thanks Wim. Been struggling with this one for 40 minutes.

Comment: Been struggling with this. This worked perfectly for me. Thanks :)

Comment: Took way too long on this small issue, this worked for me!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple and worked perfectly. It took about 4 hours to find this. Thanks!

Comment: 5 hours of research lead me to this. Please have a virtual cookie 

Comment: @Nathan No recommendations helped.

Comment: @Wim Ombelets No recommendations helped

Comment: @rahulpatil2009 No recommendations helped

Comment: @Orion Edwards No recommendations helped

Answer (score 23):

You need to put the ItemsSource property BEFORE the SelectedItem property. I came across a blog a few days ago mentioning the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out what I was doing wrong with my XAML or View Model, when it was this all along.

Comment: Bosh, great answer!

Comment: Doesn't work  on VS  15.8.1, @rp7799 's answer worked perfect.

Answer (score 11):

I have had similar issues and it was solved by making sure I was implementing **IEquatable** properly.  When the binding occurs, it is trying to see if the objects match so make sure you are properly implementing your equality checking.

Comment: I have now tried this also.  I implemented IEquatable on MyObject and match the .id fields and return true.  That also is not having an effect.  If I add a Textbox bound to the Property it is showing the correct information upon return to the page.

Answer (score 11):

In this case, the selecteditem bind doesn't work, because the hash id of the objects are different.

One possible solution is:

Based on the selected item id, recover the object on the itemsource collection and set the selected item property to with it.

Example:

```
<ctrls:ComboBoxControlBase SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedProfile, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Profiles, Mode=OneWay}" IsEditable="False" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

The Property binded to ItemSource is:

```
public ObservableCollection<Profile> Profiles
{
   get { return this.profiles; }
   private set { profiles = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Profiles"); }
}
```

The property binded to SelectedItem is:

```
public Profile SelectedProfile 
{
    get { return selectedProfile; }
    set
    {
        if (this.SelectedUser != null)
        {
            this.SelectedUser.Profile = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedProfile");  
        } 
    } 
}
```

The recovery code is:

```
    [Command("SelectionChanged")]
    public void SelectionChanged(User selectedUser)
    {
        if (selectedUser != null)
        {
            if (selectedUser is User)
            {
                if (selectedUser.Profile != null)
                {
                    this.SelectedUser = selectedUser;
                    this.selectedProfile = this.Profiles.Where(p => p.Id == this.SelectedUser.Profile.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    MessageBroker.Instance.NotifyColleagues("ShowItemDetails"); 
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

I hope it helps you.
I spent a lot of my time searching for answers, but I couldn´t find.

Answer (score 4):

When leaving the current page, the `CollectionView` associated with the `ItemsSource` property of the `ComboBox` is purged. And because the `ComboBox` `IsSyncronizedWithCurrent` property is true by default, the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` properties are reset.
This seems to be an internal data type issue in the binding. As others suggested above, if you use `SelectedValue` instead by binding to an int property on the viewmodel, it will work.
A shortcut for you would be to override the `Equals` operator on MyObject so that when comparing two MyObjects, the actual `Id` properties are compared.

Another hint: If you do restructure your viewmodels and use `SelectedValue`, use it only when `SelectedValuePath=Id` where `Id` is `int`. If using a string key, bind to the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` instead of `SelectedValue`.

Comment: I've had a very similar issue. The reason of the issue was that the ItemsSource was bound to a RelativeSource and the SelectedItem/SelectedValue was bound directly to the DataContext. I was able to solve it but the reason of the issue is not clear. It is described here for anyone with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739513/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selectedvalue-is-cleared-when-navigating-away

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed this behavior before as well.  I have noticed that the SelectedIndex property doesn't cause the same bug.  If you can restructure your ViewModel to expose the index of the selected item, and bind to that, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem with a ComboBox displaying a list of colors ( List<Brush> ).
Selecting a color was possible but it wasnt displayed when the selection closed (although the property was changed!)

**The fix was overwriting the Equals(object obj) method** for the type selected in the ComboBox (Brush), which wasnt simple because Brush is sealed.
So i wrote a class **EqualityBrush** containing a Brush and implementing Equals:

```
public class EqualityBrush
{
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (o is EqualityBrush)
        {
            SolidColorBrush b = ((EqualityBrush)o).Brush;
            return b.Color.R == this.Brush.Color.R && b.Color.G == this.Brush.Color.G && b.Color.B == this.Brush.Color.B;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Using a List of my new EqualityBrush class instead of normal Brush class fixed the problem!

My Combobox **XAML** looks like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BuerkertBrushes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Brush, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="40">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tree:EqualityBrush}">
            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="12" Fill="{Binding Brush}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Remember that my "Brush"-Property in the **ViewModel** now has to be of Type EqualityBrush!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The thing is. The selected item doesnt know which object it should use from the collection. So you have to say to the selected item to use the item from the collection.

```
public MyObject SelectedObject
 {
      get
      {
          Objects.find(x => x.id == _selectedObject.id)
          return _selectedObject;
      }
      set
      {
           _selectedObject = value;
      }
 }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very simply answer for this problem. First add the following code to the View IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True".

Next when ever you assign a new object in the ViewModel to that Property SelectedObject should be saved to that Property and not the private member.

The viewmodel Proptery should look like this

```
    public Role SelectedObject 
    {
        get { return object; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (!object.Equals(value))
                {
                    object = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(() => SelectedObject );
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding dispatcher in UserControl_Loaded event

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() =>
 {
     combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
 }));
```

Answer (score 1):

IsSyncronizedWithCurrent=False will make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I was fighting with this issue for a while.  In my case I was using in complex type (List) as the Item Source and was using a KeyType as the selected value.  On the load event, the KeyType was getting set to null.  This caused everything to break.  None of the sub elements would get updated when the key changed.  It turned out that when I added a check to make sure the proposed value for KeyType was not null, everything worked as expected.

```
    #region Property: SelectedKey
    // s.Append(string.Format("SelectedKey : {0} " + Environment.NewLine, SelectedKey.ToString()));

    private KeyType _SelectedKey = new KeyType();
    public KeyType SelectedKey
    {
        get { return _SelectedKey; }
        set
        {
            if(value != null )
                if (!_SelectedKey.Equals(value))
                {
                    _SelectedKey = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
                }
        }
    }
    #endregion SelectedKey
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of the `SelectedValuePath` and the `SelectedValue` must be EXACTLY the same.

If for example the type of `SelectedValuePath` is `Int16` and the type of the property that binds to `SelectedValue` is `int` it will not work.

I spend hours to find that, and that's why I am answering here after so much time the question was asked. Maybe another poor guy like me with the same problem can see it.

Comment: this has confused me as well. if you use plain string for value and item, you need to define `SelectedValuePath="Content"`

Answer (score 0):

It could be the way you are applying the DataContext to the Page. In WPF, everytime you navigate to a Page everything gets re-initialized, constructor gets called, loaded methods, everything. so if you are setting your DataContext inside your View you will no doubt be blowing away that SelectedItem that the user selected. In order to avoid that use the KeepAlive property of your pages.

```
<Page KeepAlive="True" ...>
   ...
</Page>
```

This will result in only the Loaded event being fired when navigating back to a page you have already visited. So you will need to ensure that you are setting the DataContext on Initialize (either externally or within the constructor) rather than Load.

However, this will only work for that instance of the Page. If you navigate to a new instance of that page it constructor will be called again.

Comment: Because I am using the MVVM pattern there is no code behind for the XAML pages.  There is no Load event.  Everything is taking place via databinding.  For that matter the template is being selected by a DataTemplateSelector based on a property in the View Model.

Answer (score 0):

ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Use Loaded event:

```
private void cmb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (cmb.Items.Count > 0) cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;          
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also bind your SelectedIndex to a property in your ViewModel and manipulate your SelectedItem that way:

```
        public int SelectedIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedIndex; }
            set
            {
                _selectedIndex = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }    
        }
```

And in your XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" ... >
```

Answer (score 0):

If your combo box options coming from dynamic data (DB or Array) then on the backend side you need to set selected value like this:

```
ddlBank.SelectedValue = "Your Value";
```

then on xml file just set

```
IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```