# Call class and method from two strings

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, reflection, architecture

I have a WPF application that has two combo boxes, one with what I'm calling a `FileType` and one with `Actions` (add, edit, delete, etc.). Every `FileType` has a corresponding class. What I'm trying to do is for example if `FileTypeA` is selected and the action is `Add` then I want to do something along these lines:

```
void myMethod(string FileType, string Action)
{
    //using reflection find class from the FileType string, and call method Action 
    var x = new FileTypeA();
    x.Add();
}
```

if the user selects `FileTypeB` and `Delete` then the object created and the method called will change accordingly. I think this might be possible using reflection, but I'm trying to find out if there is even a better way using perhaps a generic class? since all these `FileType` classes are very similar.

Comment: Think interfaces and factories.

Comment: @RoyDictus I know how to implement the factory to return the correct object but how would I use it to call the method? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: you don't use the factory to call the method, you just define an interface, say `IFileType`, that defines all Actions, and then when you have an instance of `IFileType`, you can call its `Add` method, etc.

Comment: @RoyDictus yes but I wanted to get rid off the if/else statement completely. But think I think the answer is a factory of actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create an interface IFileType with basic methods Add,Delete,Save
Implement this interface on all fileTypes classes e.g DocFile,PdfFile etc.

Bind the List to ComboBox and use its selected Item object as cast it as IFileType and call its method via interface(Delete/Save) without doing any reflection.

I would recommend using MVVM pattern so that you can easily create separation of layer and have benefits of OOP.

Comment: Yes I'm already using MVVM. But are you saying you can cast the combo box selected item directly into an object?

Comment: yes you can cast selected item to your class object and reference its method via its interface.

Comment: check this thread on binding related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663881/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selecteditem-or-selectedvalue-not-working

Answer (score 0):

If you aim to call a certain action for item according to the selected option from ComboBox, get familiar with **[delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/900fyy8e.aspx)**. Then use the approach of binding a collection of options (with the delegate included) to ComboBox