# Selected item property doesn't react to binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've bound a text box's text and a combo box's selected item to my view model. The elements in the combo box are bound to a static property.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Texty" 
  Text="{Binding CurrentThing.Texty}" ... />

<ComboBox x:Name="Picky"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AllPickables}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentThing.Picked}" ... />
```

It seems that the binding is in effect because the text box receives the correct content. The combo box gets it's values in the list correctly too. However, the issue is that the selection isn't being made.

At first I though that it had to do with the fact that some controllers have another default for *Mode*, so I tried explicitly setting it to two-way for the combo box. No difference in behavior as far I could see.

What can I be doing wrong. How to resolve it (or at least trouble-shoot)?

I've followed every hint from all I could find as the hints are [more or less the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663881/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selecteditem-or-selectedvalue-not-working) everywhere. Nothing worked, accept the approach of setting the selected **index** instead of the selected **item**. Sadly, I don't see how I could achieve that.

I've tried adding *DisplayMemberPath*, as suggested. That didn't work **and** the items of the combo box are not present anymore. I'm guessing that *DisplayMemberPath* refers to where to get stuff to itemize from whatever is referred to in *ItemSource* (and there's no *Picked* in there).

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Picky"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AllPickables}"
  SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentOrder}"
  DisplayMemberPath="Picked" ... />
```

## Full (almost) source code for the senario

View model assignment to the main window.

```
<Window.DataContext>
  <local:Presenter/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

The view model of used (circumsized version regarding the components in question in order to be a **minimal example**).

```
public class Presenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private ObservableCollection<Thing> _allThings;

  private Thing _currentThing;
  public Thing CurrentThing
  {
    get { return _currentThing; }
    set { _currentThing = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }

  public ListCollectionView AllThingsView { get; set; }

  private IEnumerable<PickType> _allPickables;
  public IEnumerable<PickType> AllPickables
  {
    get { return _allPickables; }
    set { _allPickables = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
  }

  public Presenter()
  {
    _allThings = new ObservableCollection<Thing>(DataAccessor.GetThings());
    AllThingsView = new ListCollectionView(_allThings);
    _allPickables = DataAccessor.GetPickables();
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String name = null)
  {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}
```

Main window's code behind (the parts that relate to used controls and events). I also have a grid view called *ThingListing* in my markup, which is bound to *AllThingsView* in my view model. When I click on a record in it, the event fired is supposed to update the value of *CurrentThing* and change the tab to the one where the bound controls are placed. Everything seems to get in the right places accept the selected items for combo boxes. I also have a convenience extension method *Get*. It does what you intuitively think it would (tested back and forth since forever).

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new Presenter();
  }

  private void ThingListing_OnMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    DataContext.Get<Presenter>().CurrentThing
      = sender.Get<DataGrid>().CurrentItem.Get<Thing>();

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => tabControl.SelectedIndex = 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: "However, the issue is that the selection isn't being made." Uhm, what? Could you please add info about what you want to achieve? *Set the selected ComboBox item by writing text in the TextBox*? Or what?

Comment: @Konrad Show how AllPickables and CurrentThing are defined.

Comment: Try placing a dummy converter in the binding expression and see values passed there.

Comment: Why is SelectedItem bound to a property of CurrentThing(Picked)? It seems like that binding should be "{Binding CurrentThing}".

Comment: I've had this issue too. If possible, please try this: <ComboBox ... **DataContext="{Binding CurrentThing}"** SelectedItem="**{Binding Picked}**" ... />

Comment: I agree with FrumRoll, it sounds like SelectedItem should be bound to CurrentThing.  To display a property of Current Thing in the combobox, you should probably be using DisplayMemberPath.  ie. DisplayMemberPath="Picked"

Comment: set visual studio to show the output window and investigate what it says, usually binding errors will give you a good clue.  my guess is it will complain becuase you're trying to bind to a property of a thing when you should just bind to the thing itself and displaymemberpath shouldbe defined to tell the combobox which property to display in it

Comment: No way: FrumRoll is right!

Comment: @HermanCordes You're using *DataContext* instead of *ItemSource*. Is that what's recommended for a **combobox** control? I'm not sufficiently savvy to decide but it seems that intellisense gives me *CurrentThing* when typed after *ItemSource* but **not** when typed after *DataContext*. Please keep in mind that I might have explained the setup insufficiently well, despite my best attempt. *DataContext* contains a property called *CurrentThing*. It's not *CurrentThing* itself.

Comment: @FrumRoll My view model has several properties, one of which is *CurrentThing* (the current thing is actually one of the elements in the *AllThings* property that's shown in a data grid. I wanted to keep track of the object that constitutes a certain line in the data grid. So, in the view model I have the info on the current item. In that item, there's a property that decides what should be selected in the combo box. Sorry if I was unclear. I though it was of no importance and I tried to make the minimal example of consideration for the readers. No one likes reading irrelevant gigabytes.

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen Please see my edit in the question. I've tried that and I think I might know why your suggestion didn't work. However, you might very well be onto something. How would I go about to target the selected item and not the item source with the display member path?

Comment: SelectedItem needs to bind to the same type object as the ItemsSource.  ItemsSource is a collection of type Pickable, SelectedItem property should be of type Pickable.  Then DisplayMemberPath would show a Pickable's property.  I assume TimeFrame is a property of type Pickable

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen First - typo there. I don't know how it got there... Also - there we go! I served too limtied set of information. Sorry. No - pickables are not the same time as the current order. Pickables are time slots to be picked (e.g. AM/PM/AD/AL), while the current order has a lot of properties, **a single one** of which is of time *Pickable* and shows the picked portion of the day (aha - that's why I wrote "time frame"). I need to bind the combo box's items to a set of type *A* and select an item based on property of type *B* (and its sub-property of type *A*). Is it possible?

Comment: @KonradViltersten I'm sorry, it wasn't my intention to replace _ItemsSource_ with _DataContext_. My intension was to use both next to eachother. Full example: <ComboBox x:Name="Picky"
  ItemsSource="{x:Static local:MainWindow.AllPickables}" DataContext="{Binding CurrentThing}" SelectedItem="{Binding Picked}" ... />.

Comment: @HermanCordes I tried what you wrote. Regrettably, it didn't carry all the way, yet. I've investigated all the contents of Output window and there's no info on anything erroneous there. The only thing hinting that something's wrong is the fact that when I type in *DataContext* attribute, intellisense gives me nothing from the view model at all. Not a single thingy from there. I have an instance of the vie model assigned as the data context to the window itself. Can it cause the collision? If so, can I access and bind to the data context of *MainWindow* somehow?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @KonradViltersten I wouldn't be too worried about the DataContext intellisense (yet). To answer your 1st question: generally it won't cause a collision. 2nd: if your combobox is a child of the <Window> element of the MainWindow, it already has the correct DataContext. The sample I gave you should narrow the DataContext for the ComboBox, but apparently it's not enough. Is it possible you update your question with your MainWindow's viewmodel, the viewmodel assignment to the MainWindow and the MainWindow code behind file (eg. AllPickables property).

Comment: @HermanCordes Great clarification. And yes, I can do that. I just added it. Hopefully, it'll bring some clarity and remedies any confusion I might have caused. Since it seems to be a hard one and people underestimated the complexity of it (possible due to insufficient information being provided, no blame game intended), I'm putting bounty on it as a token of my appreciation for your effort.

Comment: Please show `class Thing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the comparison fails when the view model is being read. This likely happens because of incorrect/missing implementation of comparison methods. Try implementing Equals and GetHash and see if it works.

```
public override bool Equals(Object input)
{
  return Id == ((Thing)input)?.Id;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return base.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a `ComboBox` in WPF its essential to have `SelectedItem` set to an object present in `ItemsSource` in your case in `IEnumerable<PickType> AllPickables` and in XAML `ItemSource` must be positioned **before** `SelectedItem` (as you already have it)

At the time the `ComboBox` sees `SelectedItem` it must be present in its `Items`. This rule also applies at a later time i.e. when `NotifyPropertyChanged` fires.

Further: `CurrentThing` should have the same type `PickType`

```
public PickType CurrentThing { ... }
```

and `CurrentThing` shoud point to one existing member in `AllPickables` (or set to null for no selection).