# WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedValue is cleared when navigating away

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I've had an issue with the WPF `ComboBox` that I was eventually able to solve. The reason of the issue however is not clear.

The issue occurred when using a `ComboBox` where the `ItemsSource` was referencing a different `DataContext` than the `SelectedValue`. When doing this and navigating away, the `SelectedValue` property was set to `null`. Since some properties contain logic when changing (when field A changes, also change field B), some logic was executed incorrectly.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Sector" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.SectorList}" 
                     SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SectorId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I've found several similar issues (this one was probably the closest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5033924/3357566), but none solved my problem. A lot of fixes had to do with the order of loading the `ItemsSource` and `SelectedValue` so this put me on the right track.

Instead of getting the `DataContext` from the `UserControl` through `RelativeSource`s, I've traversed the ViewModels parents to find the SectorList, so the XAML is now as follows (notice the **Root** property):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Sector" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Root.SectorList}" 
                     SelectedValuePath="Id" 
                     SelectedValue="{Binding SectorId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Can someone give me an explanation why the latter code doesn't clear the SelectedValue when leaving a page and the first one does?

**Edit**

To clarify the structure of the `ViewModels`:

- CustomerEntryViewModel

  - SectorList (and other lists to fill `ComboBoxes` which are only used in the `CustomerEntryViewModel`)
  - CustomerViewModel (separate `ViewModel` to reuse in other modules)

    - Name
    - Address
    - SectorId
    - ...

The `DataContext` of the View is `CustomerEntryViewModel` but its first container has the `DataContext` set to the `CustomerViewModel`. So to get to the `SectorList` from here, I either have to go to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` through `RelativeSource` (first example) or I have to traverse my `ViewModel` parents to the top (second example).

The question remains as to why the behavior is different between the two examples.

Comment: Instead of binding to SelectedValue, why not bind to SelectedItem?

Comment: The problem is the same with SelectedItem. The problem probably has something to do with the way RelativeSource works compared to binding to the current DataContext directly.

Comment: >I've put the logic of finding the top DataContext in the ViewModels  -- this seems inherently wrong to me. The viewmodels have access to the underlying models... why would you need to go back to DataContexts?

Comment: Lynn, thanks for your answer. Bad phrasing from my part, I meant the ViewModel tree is traversed to find the List in a parent ViewModel. I've modified the question and added some more information about the VieModels and the View.

Comment: bind to selectedindex and than access items by index in your Root.SectorList

Comment: Nikola, thanks for the feedback but the issue has nothing to do with SelectedValue, SelectedItem or SelectedIndex. They all show the same behavior in the first example: they are all set to their default value (SelectedIndex = -1) when navigating to another page.