# WPF MVVM - ComboBox binding selected value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

**EDIT**
Solution was actually a proper setting of *SelectedItem*, *SelectedValue* and *SelectedValuePath* properties.

```
<ComboBox
         Grid.Column="1"
         Padding="5"
         DisplayMemberPath="PositionName"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Positions, Mode=OneWay}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOperatorPosition, Mode=TwoWay, 
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOperatorPosition.PositionName}"
         SelectedValuePath="PositionName" />
```

**QUESTION**
I am trying to bind ComboBox SelectedValue with DataGrid SelectedItem using MVVM pattern. 
ComboBox ItemSource is *Shifts* property. I want it's SelectedValue to be bound with *SelectedShift* property, which is updated each time user selects another OperatorModel from DataGrid. 
Although *SelectedOperator* setter sets *SelectedShift* value to *SelectedOperator.Shift*, ComboBox doesn't get updated.

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIZNn.png) 
[Debugging ViewModel Property setter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFBMi.png)

My ViewModel:

```
private Operator selectedOperator;

public Operator SelectedOperator
{
    get
    {
        return selectedOperator;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedOperator = value;
        if (selectedOperator != null)
        {
            SelectedShift = selectedOperator.Shift;
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOperator));
    }
}

private Shift selectedShift;

public Shift SelectedShift
{
    get
    {
        return selectedShift;
    }
    set
    {
        selectedShift = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedShift));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox
         Grid.Column="1"
         Padding="5"
         DisplayMemberPath="Name"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Shifts}"
         SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedShift}"
         SelectedValuePath="Name" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF MVVM ComboBox SelectedItem or SelectedValue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663881/wpf-mvvm-combobox-selecteditem-or-selectedvalue-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShift}

Comment: @ZhichaoXing I have already tried different variations of SelectedItem, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath. Any of them did not work.